# Splitting a column containing varying number of values into multiple columns, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, split

I have the following table named **Company**, it has many columns but this is the problematic one:

| Team |
| --- |
| Frodo B (manager), Gandalf G (director), Batman C (cleaner) |
| John Doe (secretary), Mark Jacobs(manager), Lilly Hopes(director), Rihanna Williams (cleaner), Maddy James (supervisor), Merry Poppins (HR) |
| Rick Ross (cleaner) |
| Orlando Bloom (manager), Keira Knightly (secretary) |

Every row has different number of people followed by their position in the company in brackets. We know that there are 7 possible positions: *cleaner, director, manager, supervisor, secretary, HR, owner*

The required result is this column to be replaced by multiple columns - one for each type of position and for each row if there was someone with this position his/her name to appear in the appropriate column. The position which is in brackets is no longer needed once names fall in the right columns, I am just leaving it in the result table to better illustrate the result. The rest of the cells can be blank N/A or whatever.

| cleaner | director | manager | supervisor | secretary | HR | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Batman C | Gandalf G | Frodo B |  |  |  |  |
| Rihanna Williams (cleaner) | Lilly Hopes(director) | Mark Jacobs(manager) | Maddy James (supervisor) | John Doe (secretary) | Merry Poppins (HR) |  |
| Rick Ross (cleaner) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Orlando Bloom (manager) |  | Keira Knightly (secretary) |  |  |

I know how to do this in python but I need to make it happen in SQL Server, which is not one of my strengths unfortunately. I looked up similar questions but I cannot make it work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PIVOT` relational operator is an option:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Company
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'Frodo B (manager), Gandalf G (director), Batman C (cleaner)'),
   (2, 'John Doe (secretary), Mark Jacobs (manager), Lilly Hopes (director), Rihanna Williams (cleaner), Maddy James (supervisor), Merry Poppins (HR)'),
   (3, 'Rick Ross (cleaner)'),
   (4, 'Orlando Bloom (manager), Keira Knightly (secretary)')
) d (Id, Team)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT c.Id, LTRIM(s.[value]) AS [Name], p.Position
   FROM Company c
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.Team, ',') s
   JOIN (VALUES
      ('cleaner'), ('director'), ('manager'), ('supervisor'), ('secretary'), ('HR'), ('owner')
   ) p (Position) ON CHARINDEX(p.Position, s.[value]) > 0
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX(Name) 
   FOR Position IN ([cleaner], [director], [manager], [supervisor], [secretary], [HR], [owner])
) p
```

Result:

| Id | cleaner | director | manager | supervisor | secretary | HR | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Batman C (cleaner) | Gandalf G (director) | Frodo B (manager) |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Rihanna Williams (cleaner) | Lilly Hopes (director) | Mark Jacobs (manager) | Maddy James (supervisor) | John Doe (secretary) | Merry Poppins (HR) |  |
| 3 | Rick Ross (cleaner) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  | Orlando Bloom (manager) |  | Keira Knightly (secretary) |  |  |

For SQL Server versions before 2016 (but with XML support), you may split the stored text using well-known XML technique:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT c.Id, LTRIM(s.[value].value('.', 'varchar(1000)')) AS [Name], p.Position
   FROM (
      SELECT *, CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Team, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS XmlTeam
      FROM Company
   ) c
   CROSS APPLY c.XmlTeam.nodes('./x') s ([value])
   JOIN (VALUES
      ('cleaner'), ('director'), ('manager'), ('supervisor'), ('secretary'), ('HR'), ('owner')
   ) p (Position) ON CHARINDEX(p.Position, s.[value].value('.', 'varchar(1000)')) > 0
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX(Name) 
   FOR Position IN ([cleaner], [director], [manager], [supervisor], [secretary], [HR], [owner])
) p
```

Comment: Hello @Zhorov , thanks for the solution, it returns error
Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. This is the SMSS version: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (10.0) and  Version 15.0.2000.5.
But I think the database instance itself is older if it does not support this string split command
MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL

Is there another way to get the same result without using this method?

Comment: In English, the Company table has other columns such as Company type etc etc, which I need to include in the final result but when I try to replace c.Id with c.* it returns error: """ Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "XmlAuditors" is "xml", which is not comparable."""

Comment: Hello @Zhorov , sorry for the additional question but is there a way to adjust the script so the names are displayed in the columns without their positions in the brackets. For example in the cleaner column to have just Batman C, then Rihanna Williams etc without the position repeating in brackets. Thank you for the detailed answers so far !

Comment: @SergeySergeev, replcae `... LTRIM(s.[value].value('.', 'varchar(1000)')) AS [Name] ...` with `... REPLACE(LTRIM(s.[value].value('.', 'varchar(1000)')), CONCAT('(', p.Position, ')'), '') AS [Name] ...`. Успех!

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is another (knowing that it is limited to 7 iterations):

```
with MyTable as (
select *
from (values 
 (1, 'Frodo B (manager), Gandalf G (director), Batman C (cleaner)')
,(2, 'John Doe (secretary), Mark Jacobs(manager), Lilly Hopes(director), Rihanna Williams (cleaner), Maddy James (supervisor), Merry Poppins (HR)')
,(3, 'Rick Ross (cleaner)')
,(4,'Orlando Bloom (manager), Keira Knightly (secretary)')
) T (Id, Team)
),
RCTE as ( -- Find closing bracket positions
    select Id, FromPos=1 , BctPos=charindex(')',Team), Team from MyTable
    union all
    select R.Id, FromPos=R.BctPos+2, BctPos=charindex(')', M.Team, R.BctPos+1), M.Team 
    from MyTable M 
         inner join
         RCTE R
         on R.Id=M.Id
    where charindex(')',M.Team,R.BctPos+1)>0
),
Parsed as
( select Id, Team, Member=SubString(Team,FromPos,BctPos-FromPos+1)  from RCTE)
select 
  Id
, director=min(case when Member like '%(director)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
, cleaner=min(case when Member like '%(cleaner)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
, manager=min(case when Member like '%(manager)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
, supervisor=min(case when Member like '%(supervisor)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
, secretary=min(case when Member like '%(secretary)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
, owner=min(case when Member like '%(owner)' then left(Member,len(Member)- charindex('(',Member)-1) end)
from Parsed 
group by id
order by id
```

I assumed that they are all well formed (brackets are correctly opened closed; and blanks are used consistently, etc.

Comment: Hello @tinazmu thank you for the solution. It works as it is, but when I tried to apply it to the actual table I get error

*Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "FromPos" of recursive query "RCTE".* 
Could you advise me of possible fixes, I had to change a few things and I broke it somewhere.
  I replaced these '%(director)' with other strings like '%(General director)' etc But it all seems to logically fit.

Your assumptions are correct, brackets and spaces are consistently used so no problem there.

Comment: Hi @SergeySergeev, maybe you can share the CTE using the recursion (causing the error, called RCTE in my example), if you need more help (but you already accepted an answer??)

Comment: İf you want to add other columns from yourtable, simply join it again (to parse on I'd) on the last step, leave the rcte as is.